# Make space for ads height

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, admob

Hello and Happy new year!

I'm having a strange problem with banner ads height in my activity.

Basically the ads dimensions are 320x50dp but in logcat i can see it has only 320x0dp. 
This obviously means that there's not enough space to load ads height but i don't know how to fix...

My contant_main is here:

```
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto".
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".MainActivity"
tools:showIn="@layout/activity_main">

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/aboutLinearLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:weightSum="1">


    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="400dp"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:contentDescription="Header picture"
        android:importantForAccessibility="no"
        android:maxHeight="57dp"
        android:maxWidth="57dp"
        android:src="@drawable/xm"
        android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"/>
    </LinearLayout>

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scrollView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_below="@id/aboutLinearLayout">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/aboutLinearLayout2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:weightSum="1">

     // some Switches and textviews here that i can't show you


</LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>

// Using this form to show ads becouse i don't want that it overrides scrollview when it's shown

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/layoutadmob"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_below="@id/scrollView">

    <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
        android:id="@+id/adView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        ads:adSize="BANNER"
        ads:adUnitId="@string/banner_ad_unit_id">
    </com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>

</LinearLayout></RelativeLayout>
```

Any one knows how can i free up enough space in app layout to show my banner?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your LinearLayout at the bottom is under the scrollView, which is right, but the ScrollView height is 'wrap_content' which make it all the way down in the page.
Add an attribute

```
android:layout_alignParentBottom
```

and set it to true.

Comment: inside the scrollview?